# mysql in lamp-server doesn't work

Tags: server, mysql, lamp

Just got myself a new VPS hosted at VPSDime and cannot get mysql to work (mention the host since I've never had the error before). I've had 2 fresh installs of both Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and 12.04 LTS and I've used the same command to install on both. I've found a lot of "hackish" solutions for how to solve this while searching the web but non have given result. The following is the inputs and outputs, simplified, for both systems. Both systems were fresh installs.

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
...

apt-get install lamp-server^
...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The apache server and PHP are both working fine. I've tried to reinstall mysql separately. I have no idea what to do. If you guys can't help me I'm gonna contact the support, don't expect them to solve it but perhaps they give me my money back at least... Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. In that case it was a memory issue with mysql 5.6. I have 6GB RAM and I have an issue with mysql 5.5

Comment: If that was not the problem file a bug report =(